# safe to use a water extractor on a hardwood floor?

Tags: water, paint, cleaning

We were painting a room with a spray and had some drop cloth issues.  As a result, there is a thin layer of paint on part of the floor.  Part of it is wiping up with a warm, wet rag fairly easily, but part of it is requiring some pretty heavy elbow grease along with a very wet rag to loosen up the tiny spots of paint for removal.

Since I'm already having to get the floor fairly wet with a rag (I am drying immediately afterwards with a towel) I'm wondering if it would hurt to use a water extractor.  We have the heavy duty home version rug doctor which has pretty good suction power.  My only concern is that it came with a warning not to use on hardwood floors, but this may just be CYA on the part of the manufacturer.  As far as I know the unit doesn't actually heat the water, it just dispenses whatever I put in it.

Comment: I think it might be a CYA as long as you are removing moisture it can only help.

Comment: Try linseed oil instead of water.

Comment: Unrelated to the hardwood floor issue, I noticed that the agitator doesn't actually seem to reach down far enough to give the floor a good scrubbing if it's not carpet.  Understandable since it's made for carpets, but it's so useful in other situations it's a shame it can't have an adjustment for that.